# Why is jQuery waypoints not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I have this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
```

This:

```
.icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  position: relative; /*puede ser acá */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

This other thing:

```
.icon-animate {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And finally this:

```
var $first = $('.icon');

$first.waypoint(function (){
    $first.addClass('icon-animate');
});
```

The files are named correctly and they belong to the correct folder. Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to write functions with waypoint would be the following:

```
$first.waypoint(function(direction) {
    $first.addClass('icon-animate');
});
```

You can then specify options:

```
// hit the top of your element when scrolling up
$first.waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'up') { // hit the top of your element when scrolling up
        $first.addClass('icon-animate');
    }
});

// hit the top of your element when scrolling down
$first.waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') { // hit the top of your element when scrolling down
        $first.addClass('icon-animate');
    }
});

// hit the bottom of your element when scrolling up
$first.waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'up') { 
        $first.addClass('icon-animate');
    }
}, { offset: function() { return ((-$(this).height() + $("body").height())) } });

// hit the bottom of your element when scrolling down
$first.waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') { 
        $first.addClass('icon-animate');
    }
}, { offset: function() { return ((-$(this).height() + $("body").height())) } });
```

Comment: I added a $(document).ready function and removed the offset constraint and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Please remove one of waypoints js files. It cannot include both.

```
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
```

Comment: You just made me realize that the second one should be named waypoints.js (without the jquery. part). It's still not working, but thanks for making me notice one of my many errors.